# Nim with gtk2 not compiling

Tags: gtk, gtk2, nim-lang

I am trying following code which is modified from http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Simple_windowed_application#Nim (that code compiles without any problem):

```
import gtk2

var
  win = windowNew WINDOW_TOPLEVEL
  label1 = labelNew  "first:"
  entry1 = entryNew
  label2 = labelNew  "second:"
  entry2 = entryNew
  button = buttonNew "Calculate"
  reslabel = labelNew  "Result"
  vbox = vboxNew(true, 1)
  counter = 0

proc clickedMe(o: var PButton, lab: PLabel) =
  inc counter
  label1.setText "You clicked me " & $counter & " times"

nim_init()
win.setTitle "My calculator"

vbox.add label1
vbox.add entry1
vbox.add label2
vbox.add entry2
vbox.add button
vbox.add reslabel

win.add vbox
discard win.signal_connect("delete-event", SignalFunc mainQuit, nil)
discard button.signal_connect("clicked", SignalFunc clickedMe, label)
win.showAll()
main()
```

I am using following command:

```
nim c -r mygui.nim
```

However, it is giving following error output:

```
Hint: used config file '/etc/nim.cfg' [Conf]
Hint: system [Processing]
Hint: mygui [Processing]
Hint: gtk2 [Processing]
Hint: glib2 [Processing]
Hint: atk [Processing]
Hint: pango [Processing]
Hint: gdk2pixbuf [Processing]
Hint: gdk2 [Processing]
Hint: cairo [Processing]
mygui.nim(23, 5) Error: type mismatch: got (PVBox, proc (): PEntry{.cdecl, gcsafe.})
but expected one of: 
proc add(x: var string; y: string)
proc add(x: var string; y: char)
proc add(factory: PIconFactory; stock_id: cstring; icon_set: PIconSet)
proc add(result: var string; x: int64)
proc add(x: var string; y: cstring)
proc add(items: PStockItem; n_items: guint)
proc add[T](x: var seq[T]; y: T)
proc add(container: PContainer; widget: PWidget)
proc add(result: var string; x: float)
proc add[T](x: var seq[T]; y: openArray[T])
proc add(list: PTargetList; target: gdk2.TAtom; flags: guint; info: guint)
```

I am working on Debian Stable Linux and have installed Nim 0.16.0 from Debian repository.

Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the nim language, but looking at other examples on the web makes your reference looks weird. That may be valid, but not common, see:

- https://fossies.org/linux/Pygments/tests/examplefiles/example.nim
- https://github.com/thlorenz/readarepo-zip/blob/master/3rd/pygments/tests/examplefiles/example.nim
- https://github.com/nim-lang/Aporia/blob/master/aporia.nim

The error message says it all:

```
mygui.nim(23, 5) Error: type mismatch: got (PVBox, proc (): PEntry{.cdecl, gcsafe.})
but expected one of: 
proc add(x: var string; y: string)
```

The message says you're passing the wrong type of argument on line 23, column 5. You call `vbox.add` with some arguments and it expects arguments of another type. I don't know nim, but the calling convention used here is ambiguous:

```
entry2 = entryNew
```

You interpreted this as "create an empty entry", but it can also be seen as "put a reference to the procedure entryNew in the variable entry2", which seems the problem here, hence the `got (PVBox, proc (): PEntry`.

On the other examples I linked to, people use parenthesis, like this:

```
label2 = labelNew("second:")
entry2 = entryNew()
```

That seems more logical to me, as it avoids the ambiguity. Maybe this would work too:

```
label2 = labelNew "second:"
entry2 = entryNew ""
```

But that looks error-prone to me.